# Redux Saga: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ServerResponse'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

#### Problem Statement:

I'm unable to specify **type** for the `yield call()`. The yield is calling an **API** that fetches some data from server. The of data type is **ServerResponse**. What I want to do is specify type as follows:

`const response: ServerResponse = yield serverCall();`

But I Typescript throws this error: `Redux Saga: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ServerResponse'`.

#### Code:

```
function* serverSaga(): Generator {
  try {
    // TS throws error here;
    const response: ServerResponse = yield serverCall();
    ...
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
}

const serverCall = async (): Promise<ServerResponse> => {
  try {
    const response =  await ...
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: `Generator` is a generic.  You should be writing something like `serverSage(): Generator<some, cool, types>{}`.  I forget which parameter is which.

Comment: @zero298 would great if you can let me know about params 

Comment: Can you post more of `serverSaga`?  Does it return anything or make any other `yield`s?  Those would affect the type of the Generator as well.  If you are using VSCode, remove the return typing and see what it automatically generates.  Use that as the basis for the return.

Comment: @zero298 yes, the `serverSaga` does make more `yields` as well. And VS code doesn't auto generate return types for functions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to type your `Generator` generic, and should also be using `call` to actually call to the async function:

```js
import {
  call,
  CallEffect
} from "redux-saga/effects";

function* serverSaga(): Generator<CallEffect<ServerResponse>, void, never> {
  try {
    // TS throws error here;
    const response: ServerResponse = yield call(serverCall);
    ...
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
}

const serverCall = async (): Promise<ServerResponse> => {
  try {
    const response =  await ...
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
};
```

The actual types that the generic Generator wants can be considered with the following example.  Complex sagas can make the generic kind of obtuse.

```
type MyGen = Generator<
  number, // Outgoing (what you might yield)
  boolean, // What could be returned
  string // Incoming (left side of yield)
>;

function* MySaga(): MyGen {
  let outgoing = 0;
  while (outgoing < 10) {
    outgoing++;
    const incoming: string = yield outgoing;
    console.log(incoming);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: That didn’t help as well. TS throws this error on yield call: `Type 'Promise<ServerResponse>' is missing the following properties from type 'SimpleEffect<"CALL", CallEffectDescriptor<ServerResponse>>': combinator, '@@redux-saga/IO', type, payload`

Comment: @VinaySharma Does `serverCall` take arguments?

Comment: No, it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has provided good answers, but alternatively you could look into this library that helps alleviate this sort of issue. I've found it pretty useful for situations like this.

- https://github.com/agiledigital/typed-redux-saga
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-redux-saga

Answer (score 1):

I used the `Generator<AllEffect<ForkEffect<never>>>` typing for the function. and it worked.

```
export default function* rootSaga(): Generator<AllEffect<ForkEffect<never>>> {
   const response = yield all([
    takeLatest(RepositoriesTypes.LOAD_REQUEST, load)
  ]);
  return response;
}
```